# Keycloak API, encrypt data

Tags: keycloak

I'm creating my own web and i'm using Keycloas as IDP. When I create users from my website, I send a curl to Keycloak, like when the user logs in my web site. My doubt is, if I open the browser inspector (with F12), I can see the credentials I'm sending by Curl. I think it's not secure so I'm looking for encrypt that data but I don't find how.
Thanks

Edit: I am using https through ingress because I have keycloak on kubernetes

Comment: It is not clear which protocol are you using and what's your setup - voted to close. BTW: OIDC SSO protocol requires HTTPS, so data in transit will be encrypted. SAML protocol offers also encryption, so HTTP can be used eventually, but general recommendation is to use HTTPS everywhere.

Comment: Hello,  I am using https through ingress because I have keycloak on kubernetes